# 404 Not Found - on Laravel 5.8 when the route already exists

Tags: apache, jwt, laravel-5.8, laravel-api

I have a laravel 5.8 project on a hosted site and I recently added JWT Authentication in order to create APIs for mobile applications. Every API I have created is working fine and sending a proper response, except sometimes I am getting a 404 Not Found error even when the route exists in api.php which I'm calling as `https://app.mydomain.com/api/apiname`.

Here's how my `.htaccess file` looks as below.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

and my `api.php` in Routes is as below,

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

use App\Http\Controllers\ApiAuthController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ApiSettingsController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ApiManageUsersController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

//api test
Route::get('/my-api-endpoint',  function  (Request $request)  {

  return response()->json(['Hello Laravel 7']);

});

//Auth Routes
Route::post('login', 'ApiAuthController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'ApiAuthController@logout');
Route::post('refresh', 'ApiAuthController@refresh');
Route::post('/rest/re_login', 'ApiAuthController@re_login');
Route::GET('/language_json', 'ApiAuthController@language_json');

//Settings Routes
Route::GET('/branding_info', 'ApiSettingsController@branding_info');
Route::POST('/update_branding_info', 'ApiSettingsController@update_branding_info');
Route::GET('/grading_master', 'ApiSettingsController@grading_master');
Route::POST('/grad_cat_active_inactive', 'ApiSettingsController@grad_cat_active_inactive');
Route::GET('/grading_master/view_lessons', 'ApiSettingsController@view_lessons');
Route::POST('/lesson_active_inactive', 'ApiSettingsController@lesson_active_inactive');
Route::GET('/driving_conditions', 'ApiSettingsController@grading_master');


//Manage Users Routes
Route::GET('/Manage_users/{user_type}', 'ApiManageUsersController@Manage_users');
```

**Note:** I am using `Plesk` to access my server.
Please help me out with this situation.

and here's a screenshot of 404 error which I get in postman,
[image]

Thanks in advance....

Comment: "except __sometimes__ I am getting a 404 Not Found". When do you get back a successful response and when do you get back a `404 Not Found`?

Comment: Without any more information, this could pretty much mean that you host provider has poor availability

Comment: What is the apiname, I need to know the apiname and the method you are using to check what is going on? 404 if you didn't know is when the apiname or the method is wrong, so the server doesn't know what to do.